# Display WooCommerce variable product price on other pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm using WooCommerce on a WordPress site that I'm building and I need to be able to display a specific product's price throughout the site. Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but in this instance it's a product which has 2 variations, so I need to show both of them (e.g. £4.99 - £9.99). How can I retrieve these values and echo them out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function so_28073705( $product_id ) {

    $wc_product_variable  =  new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );

    $variation_price_html  =  $wc_product_variable->get_price_html( );

    return $variation_price_html;

}
```

## When you want to use it:

```
<?php echo so_28073705( <product_id> ); ?>
```

## returns:

```
<span class="amount">$low-price</span>–<span class="amount">$high-price</span>
```